# How can I Subtitute The Value of The First and The Last Row of Category with '0' using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am still a newbie with python. I have a problem like this:

I would like to substitute the value of the first and the last row with 0. Here's my data (stored in Dataframe):

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-1 | 500 |
| 2000-1 | 200 |
| 2000-1 | 20 |
| 2000-1 | 350 |
| 2000-2 | 250 |
| 2000-2 | 210 |
| 2000-2 | 320 |
| 3000-1 | 330 |
| 3000-1 | 370 |
| 3000-1 | 85 |
| 4000-3 | 91 |
| 4000-3 | 92 |
| 4000-3 | 88 |
| 4000-5 | 87 |
| 4000-5 | 77 |
| 4000-5 | 76 |

And here's the expected output:

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-1 | 0 |
| 2000-1 | 200 |
| 2000-1 | 20 |
| 2000-1 | 0 |
| 2000-2 | 0 |
| 2000-2 | 210 |
| 2000-2 | 320 |
| 3000-1 | 0 |
| 3000-1 | 370 |
| 3000-1 | 0 |
| 4000-3 | 0 |
| 4000-3 | 92 |
| 4000-3 | 0 |
| 4000-5 | 0 |
| 4000-5 | 77 |
| 4000-5 | 0 |

Thank you, need your help

Comment: How is your data stored? List? Array? Dataframe?

Comment: @Pepsi-Joe hi Joe, It's Dataframe

Answer (score 1):

If the values in "Value" are unique for each "Category" (like in the example), we could:

(i) `groupby` "Category" and select column "Value"

(ii) Find the first and last elements of each group

(iii) Create a boolean mask that identifies first and last elements of each group

(iv) use the mask on `df['Value']` and assign 0.

```
gb_obj = df.groupby('Category')['Value']    
firsts = gb_obj.transform('first')
lasts = gb_obj.transform('last')
msk = (df['Value'] == firsts) | (df['Value'] == lasts)
df.loc[msk, 'Value'] = 0
```

If not, we can apply a function to "Value" that assigns 0 to first and last element in each group:

```
def first_last_to_zero(g):
    g.iloc[0] = g.iloc[-1] = 0
    return g

df['Value'] = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].apply(first_last_to_zero)
```

Output:

```
   Category  Value
0    2000-1      0
1    2000-1    200
2    2000-1     20
3    2000-1      0
4    2000-2      0
5    2000-2    210
6    2000-2      0
7    3000-1      0
8    3000-1    370
9    3000-1      0
10   4000-3      0
11   4000-3     92
12   4000-3      0
13   4000-5      0
14   4000-5     77
15   4000-5      0
```

Comment: This may fail if an individual category contains duplicate numbers.  For example, if 2000-1 contained more than one value of 500.

Comment: @jch you're right. I edited to include another option that handles a more general option.

Answer (score 1):

Via `transform()`:

```
def first_last_0(x):
    x.iloc[0] = 0 
    x.iloc[-1] = 0
    return x

df['Value'] = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].transform(first_last_0)

0       0
1     200
2      20
3       0
4       0
5     210
6       0
7       0
8     370
9       0
10      0
11     92
12      0
13      0
14     77
15      0
```